# The global/xdg file 'ignore' doesn't exist: No such file or directory

Tags: libgit2

I'm trying the implement a `git checkout {branch}`.
The code is as follows:

```
bool GitHandler::checkoutBranch(std::string branchName){

  bool error = 0;

  git_checkout_options opts;
  git_checkout_init_options(&opts, GIT_CHECKOUT_OPTIONS_VERSION);
  opts.checkout_strategy = GIT_CHECKOUT_SAFE;

  git_object *treeish = NULL;
  error = error || git_revparse_single(&treeish, repo, branchName.c_str());
  assert(treeish != NULL); // The branch exists

  error = error || git_checkout_tree(repo, treeish, &opts);

  printf("%s\n", giterr_last()->message);
  git_object_free(treeish);

  return !error;
}
```

The problem is that whenever I try to run this code I get the following exception `The global/xdg file 'ignore' doesn't exist: No such file or directory` printed from that printf statement. However `git checkout {branch}` succeeds. What could be the issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

That error message is due to the repository startup and it's not the reason for an error. If you call `giterr_clear()` before your operation, it won't show up.

The return value of libgit2 functions is `int`. If you try to stuff it into a bool, anything could happen.

You also print out the error message unconditionally. If there was no error during the checkout, it makes sense that it will print out that error string.

What makes you think this code isn't working?  Are either of these functions returning an error? If you're expecting `git_checkout_tree()` to switch branches, as your `git checkout {branch}` comment seems to suggest, then you won't ever observe that result. libgit2's checkout restricts itself to dealing with files. If you wish to change what the current branch is, you need to set HEAD with `git_repository_set_head()` or similar.